# Why are glueballs or particles made entirely of gluons unstable?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, gluons

I am wondering why glueballs or particles made entirely of gluons are unstable. What prompts them to decay because each individual gluon themselves are massless and only together are they massive. So how does the decay work and why does it occur?

Comment: Particles that do have mass need a very good reason to be stable.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball#Stability_and_decay_channels) has a diagram of one possible decay into two pions. It can decay like this because there is no conservation law preventing it from doing so. “Everything which is not forbidden is mandatory,” with some probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an experimental fact that gluons, in contrast to photons with which they share the zero mass and spin 1 as the gauge bosons of [the standard model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) cannot be observed  outside the nucleus. There exists a gluon-gluon interaction in contrast to the case of the photon, that keeps them bound. It is the standard model that predicts their existence within the nucleus,and the  theory  is very successful in fitting the data and observations, so  existence of gluons  within the nucleus  *is assumed* correct. (The same is true for quarks).

Thus the existence of glueballs is an extension of the mathematics of the standard model.  They are predicted, and sought experimentally , but [only their decays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball#Stability_and_decay_channels) can be observed outside the nuclear environment, as suggested in the comments. Whole glueballs cannot come out of the nuclear environment, as far as the mathematics of our present theories go. Have a look [here for the physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4453) of glueballs.

Comment: Is glueball decay something that occurs naturally, and all the time?  That is, are there tons of pions leaving protons all the time?

Comment: @foolishmuse this would violate energy and momentum conservation !!! The proton is a bound state auntum mechanically with a specific mass.

Comment: Just to clarify, since it seems like two concepts are being mixed up: one cannot measure a freely-propagating gluon because, roughly, confinement prevents one from seeing particles with color charge; however, one can form glueballs which are colorless (SU(3)-singlet) states and thus should propagate. However, if I understand correctly, they decay relatively quickly since the binding energies are quite large, and there are much lighter states which glueballs can decay into (like pions).